# Shell script to fix bad filenames?

Tags: shell-script, freebsd, afp

I'm IT at my small firm; and, despite my dire warnings, everyone puts files on the server with awful names, including leading & trailing spaces, bad characters (including `\ ; / + . < > -` etc!)

They do this by accessing the (FreeBSD/FreeNAS) server via AFP on Macs, so no part of the system complains.

Is there a script I can use to go through an entire directory tree and fix bad filenames?

Basically replace all spaces & bad ASCII with `_` ... and if a file already exists, just slap a `_2` or something on the end.

I don't suppose there's a way to get the system to *enforce* good filenaming conventions, is there?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't tell netatalk or whatnot to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use bash and find. I'm sure there's a simpler option but here's what I came up with:

1. This can deal with file names containing "/" (find will give a warning, ignore it), but **it will only work on files in the current directory** (no subdirectories). I couldn't figure out how to tell bash or find to differentiate between a "/" in a file name and a "/" that is part of the path.

   ```
   for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  -name "*[\:\;><\@\$\#\&\(\)\?\\\/\%]*" | sed 's/\.\///'); do mv "$i" ${i//[\;><\@\$\#\&\(\)\?\\\/\%]/_}; done
   ```
2. This one **cannot** deal with file names containing "/" but it will work on all files in the current directory **and its subdirectories**:

   ```
   for i in $(find . -type f  -name "*[\:\;\>\<\@\$\#\&\(\)\?\\\%]*"); do mv "$i" ${i//[\;><\@\$\#\&\(\)\?\\\%]/_}; done
   ```

Make sure to **test these before running**. They worked fine in the few tests I ran, but I was not exhaustive. Also bear in mind that I am on a linux system. The particular implementation of find, and perhaps bash, may differ on yours.

---

EDIT: Changing the `mv $i` command to `mv -i $i‘ will cause mv to prompt you before overwriting an existing file.

EDIT2: To deal with filenames with spaces, you can change the bash IFS (Input Field Separator) variable like so (adapted from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html)):

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS; IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b"); for i in $(find . -type f  -name "*[\:\;\>\<\@\$\#\&\(\)\?\\\%\ ]*"); do mv "$i" ${i//[\;><\@\$\#\&\(\)\?\\\%\ ]/_}; done; IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

I also modified the regular expression to match/replace spaces with underscores. The SAVEIFS bit just returns the IFS variable to its original configuration.

---

EXPLANATION:

```
for i in $(command); do something $i; done
```

This is a generic bash loop. It will go through a command's output, sequentially setting variable $i to each of the values returned by command, and will do something to it.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  -name "*[\:\;><\@\$\#\&\(\)\?\\\/\%]*" '
```

Find all files in the current directory whose name contains one of the following characters: `:;><@$#&()\/%`. To add more, just escape them with "\" (eg "\¿") and add them to the list within the brackets ([ ]). Probably, not all these characters need to be escaped, but I can never remember which are special variables in which environment so I escape everything, just in case.

```
sed 's/\.\///
```

Remove the current directory from find's output, print "foo" instead of "./foo".

```
mv "$i" ${i//[\;><\@\$\#\&\(\)\?\\\/\%]/_}
```

Every time this little scipt loops, $i will be the name of a badly named file. This command will move (rename) that file changing all unwanted characters to "_". Look up bash substitution for more information.

---

Comment: This looks good, but (a) I had to change the `"..."` in the find expression to `'...'`; and (b) when I try to run the loop, it says `do: command not found.` Maybe a FreeBSD limitation? Or csh?

Comment: It was csh ... works better after I `exec bash`!

Comment: @Ze'ev Yup, you definitely need bash for this. The substitution command is also bash specific. You can try and automate the file renaming process by introducing a variable that will be incremented every time you have 2 files with the same name.

Comment: Using bash is fine; almost working. But there is a problem with filenames with a space in them. If I have a file called `./a/b/c/xxx$ 111`, then the find command returns `./a/b/c/xxx$` and `111` as two separate items in `$i`, and then the `mv` fails.

Comment: The strange thing is that `find` on its own returns just the one file, including the space; but the `find` within the loop breaks it into 2 results.

Comment: @Ze'ev Yeah, the problem is that bash, by default uses a space to separate entries. Bash does not like spaces in filenames. Hang on, I'll update the answer in a second.

Comment: Hey, couldn't I use the `-exec` option of `find` ?

Comment: Something like: `Find . -name "*.model" -exec mv "{}" ``echo "{}" | sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9_./]/_/g'`` \;`

Comment: @Ze'ev I played around with that for this answer and couldn't get it to work. The problem was making find differentiate between slashes in a filename and actual paths. I also had some other complication I can't remember. If you can make it work, more power to you :) In any case, the updated answer should work.