# How to quickly rename (batch or soft) ext files for ntfs compatibility

Tags: fedora, ntfs, file-transfer, ext

I am running fedora and I would like a tool to automatically rename files on my ext3 fedora partition so that I can transfer files with incompatible names flawlessly. Any advice on how to proceed ? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I know there is a nice GUI tool for this purpose named [ext2ntfs-compatibilator](http://code.google.com/p/ext2ntfs-compatibilator/), but it doens't seem to be 64 bits compatible.

Comment: Could you give some examples please?

Comment: Like name a text file njkn??'_è' and try to copy to a ntfs or fat32 disk and it just won't do -__- ... Anything with \/:*?"<>| actually

Comment: NTFS doesn't care about most characters. You can use any UTF-16 code point except `NUL` (`U+0000`) and `/` (slash). The Win32 subsystem, as normally used by Windows (there's a POSIX subsystem for Windows), has restrictions of `NUL` and `/\:*?"<>|`. Please don't mix NTFS with the Win32 subsystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, first of all do *not* use special characters in file names, it just complicates matters :).

Have a look at my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/463742/shell-script-to-fix-bad-filenames/463761#463761).

For a GUI way try [thunar's](http://thunar.xfce.org/) bulk rename feature:

```
$ yum install thunar
$ Thunar --bulk-rename
```

1. Add the files you want to rename
2. Choose "Search and Replace"
3. Paste the regex from my linked answer (`[\:\;\>\<\@\$\#\&\(\)\?\\\%\ ]`)into the "Search For" field.
4. Write "_" into the "Replace With" field
5. Click on "Rename Files"

[image: Thunar Bulk Rename Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, its almost duplicate. But my question is more fedora and user interface oriented... I have seen one GUI tool for that but forgot the name. If I don't get a more user friendly option I'll give it a try.

Comment: Found it : ext2ntfs-compatibilator (http://code.google.com/p/ext2ntfs-compatibilator/downloads/list) the problem is it doesn't seem to be 64 bits compatible... So I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: @ZenMaster I updated my answer to include a GUI way. Also, there is nothing specific to fedora about what you are trying to do. The CLI solution I gave will work for any *nix using BASH.

Comment: The solution you provided renames only the first character, not all!

Comment: @sebix yes, I don't know how to make the replacement global with this program. If you have perl-rename (which you do on Debian based systems like Debian itself, Ubuntu or Mint), just use `rename 's/[\:\;\>\<\@\$\#\&\(\)\?\\\%\ ]/_/g' file1 file2 file3 fileN`. If you don't have perl rename, do `for i in file1 file2 fileN; do mv "$i" "${i//[\:\;\>\<\@\$\#\&\(\)\?\\\%\ ]/_}"; done`.