# View C source files (and files in other programming lanugages) in Icewasel/Firefox

Tags: firefox, c, iceweasel

How do I make C files appear in the browser's window when I navigate to them on a web page? (I use Iceweasel which should be identical to Firefox.)

I don't want to download the file, not open it in Emacs, etc., I just want to view it like any other page.

For example, Perl files (`.pl`) are OK.

But, C files (`.c`) have an option line in Preferences -> Applications. Here, I can chose what to do - download them, open in Emacs, etc., but how do I chose to just view them? (Tried to pick Iceweasel - didn't work.)

Ironic thing is, I think "view in browser" is default (as there is no option for Perl files) - so if I could somehow **remove** the option line for C, that's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. I have wanted to do this for ages but never get around to finding a solution. Your question forced me to :).

**Solution 1**

Use the [Open in Browser extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-browser/). This works perfectly well but adds some whitespace to the left of each line in the source code file.

**Solution 2**

Change all extensions to `.txt`. I often build websites for sharing my data with my collaborators. Since I work on Linux, I often have random extenions that are only informative to me. Things like `file1.out` or `file1.res` or `file1.thisbetterwork` or whatever. I cannot tell them they need to install an extension, so my webpage links to copies of the relevant files with txt extensions that I have made in my server's directory:

```
$ for i in *.c ; do cp $i /var/www/mysite/sources/$i".txt"; done
```

This assumes your file names are sane, containing **no spaces** or other strange characters. Look at my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/463761/151431) for tips on how to modify it to deal with stranger file names.

---

[This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/firefox/+bug/25830) bug offers some background. We are not alone.

Comment: **1** works perfectly (I don't get any whitespace) but, is it possible to make that default? As it is now, I have to pick "Open in browser" every time. As for **2**, that works for homepages, but __only__ for homepages - if you were to download the file, ls wouldn't know what color to show it in, Emacs won't set the correct mode, gcc won't compile a (supposed) text file, etc. etc. Although it could be automatized, I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: Forgot to ask in the above comment: The bug link you posted, that's so much to read, did you read it and didn't find a workaround?